# How can I attach a Facebook share on android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I want code that connects button 'share to Facebook' only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution.. Here I am posting the answer so that it may help other people who may have same doubt..

For Share through any application...

public void sendAppMsg(View view) {

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
String text = " message you want to share..";
// change with required  application package  

intent.setPackage("PACKAGE NAME OF THE APPLICATION");
if (intent != null) {
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, text));
} else {

    Toast.makeText(this, "App not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

}
Note : change *PACKAGE NAME OF THE APPLICATION as per your requirement like

Example : USE

//Whatsapp
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");`

//Linkedin
    intent.setPackage("com.linkedin.android");

//Twitter
    intent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");

//Facebook
    intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");

//GooglePlus
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");